# How can I make all lazy Moose features be built?

Tags: perl, moose

I have a bunch of lazy features in a Moose object.

Some of the builders require some time to finish.

I would like to nvoke all the builders (the dump the "bomplete" object).
Can I make all the lazy features be built at once, or must I call each feature manually to cause it builder to run?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `default` for that? I thought the point of `lazy` was to postpone creating the attribute value until first use. If you need all attributes to be set at object construction, `default` seems more useful. Or, you can provide your own `BUILD` method.

Comment: This is a reasonably common idiom and there are some decent reasons for it.

Comment: Basically, you could do all of the work in `BUILD` instead but it's nicer to have a method per-attribute. And if you're going to have a method per attribute to compute the value then it may as well be a builder. But if a builder is going to access other attributes then the built attribute needs to be lazy to be sure that they've been initialized. And there isn't a "lazy, but only a *little bit* lazy" attribute option :)

Comment: FWIW, this has come up a few times on #moose, and a new MX module proposed to handle this, somewhat parallel to MooseX::LazyRequire. It would allow marking attributes "this is lazy, because it depends on other attribute values to be built, but I want it to be poked before construction finishes."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to have "lazy" attributes with builders, but ensure that their values are constructed before `new` returns, the usual thing to do is to call the accessors in `BUILD`.

```
sub BUILD {
    my ($self) = @_;

    $self->foo;
    $self->bar;
}
```

is enough to get the job done, but it's probably best to add a comment as well explaining this apparently useless code to someone who doesn't know the idiom.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could use the meta class to get list of 'lazy' attributes. For example:

```
package Test;

use Moose;


has ['attr1', 'attr2'] => ( is => 'rw', lazy_build => 1);
has ['attr3', 'attr4'] => ( is => 'rw',);

sub BUILD {
    my $self = shift;


    my $meta = $self->meta;

         foreach my $attribute_name ( sort $meta->get_attribute_list ) {

         my $attribute =  $meta->get_attribute($attribute_name);

        if ( $attribute->has_builder ) {
            my $code = $self->can($attribute_name);
            $self->$code;

        }
    }

}


    sub _build_attr1 { 1 }
    sub _build_attr2 { 1 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I've had this exact requirement several times in the past, and today I actually had to do it from the metaclass, which meant no BUILD tweaking allowed. Anyway I felt it would be good to share since it basically does exactly what ether mentioned:

> 'It would allow marking attributes "this is lazy, because it depends
>   on other attribute values to be built, but I want it to be poked
>   before construction finishes."'

However, derp derp I have no idea how to make a CPAN module so here's some codes:
https://gist.github.com/TiMBuS/5787018

Put the above into Late.pm and then you can use it like so:

```
package Thing;
use Moose;
use Late;

has 'foo' => (
    is      => 'ro',
    default => sub {print "setting foo to 10\n"; 10},
);

has 'bar' => (
    is      => 'ro',
    default => sub {print 'late bar being set to ', $_[0]->foo*2, "\n"; $_[0]->foo*2},
    late    => 1,
);

#If you want..
__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
1;


package main;

Thing->new();
#`bar` will be initialized to 20 right now, and always after `foo`.
#You can even set `foo` to 'lazy' or 'late' and it will still work.
```